# Как сохранить каждый файл в отдельную папку?

Tags: delphi

В предоставленном коде идет разбитие просто на файлы, но нужно что бы программа сохраняла каждый, разбитый файл в отдельную папку.

Например:

```
Каталог_1\Файл_1
Каталог_2\Файл_2
Каталог_3\Файл_3
```

Делал вот так, но ничего не выходит:

```
ForceDirectories(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\Katalog\' +'Fayl' + inttostr(i));
    AssignFile(F2, '\Katalog\'+'Fayl'+ inttostr(i));
```

Код программы (без правок):

```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    F1, F2: TextFile;
    SizeFile, SizePart, SizePartLast, i, j, N: cardinal;
    TempStr: string;
  begin
    if OpenDialog1.InitialDir = '' then
      OpenDialog1.InitialDir := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);

    if not OpenDialog1.Execute then Exit;

    AssignFile(F1,OpenDialog1.FileName);
    Reset(F1);
    SizeFile := 0;
    //подсчитаем количество строк
    while not eof(F1) do
    begin
      readln(F1,tempstr);
      inc(SizeFile);
    end;
    //вернемся в начало файла
    Reset(F1);
    //разобьем файл на заданное количество частей
    N := 10;
    SizePart := SizeFile div N;
    SizePartLast := SizePart;
    if SizeFile mod N > 0 then
    begin
      SizePart := SizePart + 1;
      SizePartLast := SizeFile - SizePart * (N - 1);
    end;
    for i := 1 to N - 1 do
    begin
      AssignFile(F2, OpenDialog1.FileName + '.part' + IntToStr(i));
      Rewrite(F2);
      for j := 1 to SizePart do
      begin
        readln(F1,TempStr);
        writeln(F2,TempStr);
      end;
      CloseFile(F2);
    end;
    //обработка последнего куска
    AssignFile(F2, OpenDialog1.FileName + '.part' + IntToStr(N));
    Rewrite(F2);
    for j := 1 to SizePart do
    begin
      readln(F1,TempStr);
      writeln(F2,TempStr);
    end;
    CloseFile(F2);
    CloseFile(F1);
  end;
```

Comment: А где в коде папкам даются разные имена?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Каталог_1\Файл_1
ForceDirectories(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Katalog_' + IntToStr(i));
AssignFile(F2, ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Katalog_' + IntToStr(i) + '\Fayl_' + IntToStr(i));
```